# export contacts to mail chimp integration with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailchimp

"i want to upload email contacts to mailchimp by using api key and list id provided by the user ,and the list of email in the database will be uploaded to mailchimp that particular listId"

Comment: @Robert ok my fault...i should have done really better...anyways thanx for suggestion...i'll tc from next time.and i have solved this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first of all you have to download this library folder http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/**

the example below is for **codeigniter**

1. include MCAPI.class file in your helper folder
2. then rename it as MCAPI_helper.php
3. now you add the below code to your controller.

   ```
   function index()
   {

       $apikey = "****mail chimp api key***";
       $listId = "****list id key***"; 
       $my_email ="testing@gmail.com";
       $api = new MCAPI($apikey);



       $merge_vars = array("FNAME"=>'SANDEEP', "LNAME"=>'KUMAR');
   ```

   // if you want to take a confirmation from the user than set $double_optin=true

   ```
       $retval = $api->listSubscribe( $listId, $my_email,    $merge_vars,$email_type='html', $double_optin=false );

       if ($api->errorCode){
           echo "Unable to load listSubscribe()!\n";
           echo "\tCode=".$api->errorCode."\n";
           echo "\tMsg=".$api->errorMessage."\n";
       } else {
           echo "the contact is added to you list";
       }


   }
   ```